# PHP case errors

Tags: case, php

```
Line 9: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CASE:
line:"case "reinstall"
```

Code:

```
 if ( check_permissions( "hardware_info", "" ) )
    {
        $link_hardware_info = link_to( $label = $singlerow_hardware['display'], $path = "hardware/info/{$singlerow_setup['hardware_id']}" );
        $col2_array[] = li_links( "{$img_arrow_up} {$link_hardware_info}" );
    }
    break;
case "reinstall" :
    do
    {
        $module_page_title = translate_text( "tpl_store_reinstall" );
        $singlerow_install = query_singlerow( $table = "store_installs", "`id` = '{$load_module_id}'" );
        $singlefield_hardware_id = query_singlefield( $table = "store_setups", "hardware_id", "`id` = '{$singlerow_install['setup_id']}'" );
        $label_display_store = query_singlefield( $table = "store_produts", "display", "`id` = '{$singlerow_install['product_id']}'" );
        $link_information_up = link_to( $label = $label_display_produtct, $link = "installs/info/{$load_module_id}" );
        $col2_array[] = li_links( "{$img_arrow_up} {$link_information_up}" );
        $dbform_array['file_id'] = $singlerow_install['file_id'];
        $html_main .= form_default( $path = "installs/reinstall/{$load_module_id}" );
        $html_main .= form_fieldset( );
        $html_main .= form_legend( $legend = translate_text( "tpl_auto_install" )." ".translate_text( "tpl_package" ) );
        if ( !empty( $postdata_valid['file_id'] ) )
        {
            $setup_type = query_singlefield( $table = "store_files", "setup", "`id` = '{$postdata_valid['file_id']}'" );
            if ( $setup_type == "archive" )
            {
                $link_store_reinstall_id = squeezebox( $label = translate_text( "tpl_store_reinstall", "lower" ), $link = "connect/reinstall/{$load_module_id}/?reinstall_file_id={$postdata_valid['file_id']}" );
            }
```

I already have try whith another solution but not worked,

```
case "reinstall":do_function_reinstall();do_function_reinstall();  break;function do_function_reinstall();
```

Comment: Please expand your post. Include your code in your question, and ask a question.

Comment: The only place you can use a case, is within a switch, could you show the switch as well?

Comment: This is odd: `link_to( $label = $singlerow_hardware['display'], $path = "hardware/info/{$singlerow_setup['hardware_id']}" )`. PHP does not have named arguments. Are you trying to convert rails methods into php?

Comment: Thanks john to post the entire code.

Comment: if ( !( $current_login_type == "subuser" ) )
    {
        break;
    }
    $col2_array[] = li_links( "<hr />" );
    $link_accounts_info = link_to( $label = "{$singlerow_user['fname']} {$singlerow_user['lname']}", $path = "accounts/info/{$singlerow_setup['user_id']}" );
    $col2_array[] = li_links( "{$img_arrow_up} {$link_accounts_info}" ); this is before the all content i cant post or edit the code  ctrl+K. sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is not clear enough ! because the CASE statement is used after using the switch statement but as i see their were no switch statement in your code so i don't know if this is a type or not

Then the using of the case must be look like this :

```
switch(VARIABLE_NAME)
    {
        case "reinstall":{//Here put your instructions}
    }
```

Try this and tell me the result :)

Comment: Hi last,your code have made my day thans very much

Comment: For nothing ! I am glad that my solution has helped you :) And i am here for any help :)

Comment: Hi,i have another question, if i have 4 cases,exemple : case 1 case2 case3 case4 how i can do? "switch(VARIABLE_NAME)
    {
        case "1","2","3","4":{My code} doesnt work,maybe someone can help me.Thanks.

Comment: @mind : Hello as you can see that if you have 4 case or more than 10 cases the concept is the same :)

switch(VARIABLE_NAME)
    {
       case "resinstall" : {//Your code;break;}
       case "uninstall" :  {//Your code;break;}
       case "install" : {//your code;break;}
       default : {//Your code;break;}
    }

We use break to enforce the script to stop when he encounters a valid condition and do not skip it to the next condition tests

If any help need i am here :)

Comment: Well the problem is my intered code is after the 4 cases,case "1": case "2": case "3": case "4":   Maybe i nedd to change my code.

Comment: Hello @mind ! Please clear your question enough that i can help you the maximum . If you can post your real code here or the part where your problem have status it will  be great :)

Comment: i cant post the code here because just a parte of the code was 300 lines :)

Comment: Hello @mind : I think that this link may help you : Try it then tell me if that was the solution :)

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Any clarification needed just tell me :)

Comment: Hi@ last breath i gonna see this link and i gonna try make some modification in my code and see if works thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `case` keyword may only appear within a `switch` block. Make sure your code looks similar to this:

```
switch($variable) {
    case "foo":
        // code to handle when $variable == "foo"
    break;
    case "reinstall":
       do
       {
           // loop content
       } while (condition); // make sure there is a semicolon here.
    break;
}
```